# How to validate SM_USER header in Spring Security preauthentication for siteminder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, siteminder, pre-authentication

I 'm trying to create a secure spring rest api using pre-authentication security for siteminder.

I 've tried a solution where I 'm getting SM_USER and when I tested it in postman by adding new header SM_USER with random value it seems to work fine.

If you don't provide header I'm getting an error org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException: SM_USER header not found in request which is valid.

But how can I be sure that this is secure? if someone knows the URL of my rest api could call this without problem. Should I check something else in spring or  only siteminder offers user authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The front-end SiteMinder web agent is the guaranty that the session is valid - you **must** make sure via server/network configuration that your application cannot be accessed directly without first passing through the SiteMinder web agent.

Also, SiteMinder asserts multiple headers. `SM_USER` should not be used alone because it can be asserted by the web agent in some circumstances when the user does not actually have a valid session. Instead, you should **first** look for the existence (non-blank) of `SM_SERVERSESSIONID`, which only exists if the session is valid.

Lastly, I generally try to avoid `SM_USER` at all - because `SM_USER` is actually not a user attribute at all, but rather is "the login identifier used for authentication". If SiteMinder authenticates users via federation (e.g. SAML) or x509 authentication, `SM_USER` will be rather different than if a login form was used. Instead, its better in SiteMinder to set a "universal id" that is a user attribute, and appears in the headers as `SM_UNIVERSALID`. Your SiteMinder administrators will know how to do this (and may already have - look to see if you have a `SM_UNIVERSALID` header available already).

One other caution, in some SiteMinder configurations, the underscore will not be in the header name (use of the underscore is called "legacy" header mode in SiteMinder), so you might want to make your app configurable with respect to the header names, e.g. `SMSERVERSESSIONID`, `SMUSER`, `SMUNIVERSALID` etc.

If you want to programmatically re-validate a session, you can use the SiteMinder Agent API or REST API, or look at my company's product "SSO/Rest" which provides a comprehensive set of uniform REST interfaces to SiteMinder and also other SSO providers (http://www.idfconnect.com).

HTH!

-Richard